# AppScript and Access in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can I open access to the sheets for editing, with the ability to run scripts. But do not give access to viewing and editing scripts?
Or how can I give users access to run scripts without changing them?

Comment: Make a standalone script and [publish it as an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is easily done. However, from experience, ensure you extensively test your scripts and add all the necessary error handling before distributing it.

Basically, what you need to do it create a new standalone script file, save a version and then distribute the project key to your users or if you are creating a template that the user will make a copy of then call the functions in the script editor of the template file.

[Google Documentation on creating librarys](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

[Google Documentation on creating a version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#creating_a_version)